# Phone call button in Xcode 8.2 does not work

Tags: xcode

I'm making an app where I need a Call Us button. When pressed, it should dial a specific number, and when complete, return to app.

I used the following :

```
-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {     
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://2135554321"]
    ]; 
}
```

But get an error by xcode

> "Expected declaration"

No matter what I try, I get an error.  Can you Please assist?  Thank You.